# Client to access and edit a MySQL database remotely

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access

So I have been given the host, username, and login information for a MySQL Database. I need a client that I can use to log in to the Database remotely and create/update tables and edit all the data.

I found the MySQL Administrator client provided by them, but it seems you can do everything BUT edit the actual data with it.

Is there anything like this?

Would I be able to use SQL Server Express (or something similar), to connect to a remote server online and do all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the mysql administrator, you normally get the mysql query browser, which sounds like what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OS X or Linux, you can install the mysql client and connect via the console. There are plenty of GUI clients for OS X and Windows (SqlYOG is a good, free one that I've used), just search Google for "mysql client ".

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) works great for me.  It allows me to connect to some remotely hosted databases that I have via ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [SqlYog Community Edition](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/) which inkedmn also mentioned. It handles database administration and query building, and similar enough to SQL Server Management Studio that you won't feel completely lost.